# stop tensorflow and clear gram

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

There is something wrong with the fan my GPU. So the temperature of GPU would be too higher after running tensorflow for a while. And I can't finish my training before the overheating of gpu. So I write a script to detect the temperature and  try to pause the program to let the gpu cool down. The code is like this (the threshold is setted to 45 for test):

```
        for batch in batches:
            temp = int(os.popen("nvidia-smi | awk '{if(NR == 12)print $3}' | cut -c 1,2").readline().strip())
            x_batch,y_batch,user_batch,item_batch = zip(*batch)
            train_step(x_batch, y_batch, user_batch, item_batch)
            current_step = tf.train.global_step(sess, self.global_step)
            if temp>=45:
                path = saver.save(sess, checkpoint_prefix, global_step=current_step)
                print("temperature of GPU is over 45! Saved model checkpoint to {}\n".format(path))
                sess.close()
                return (-1,path,batches)
```

I wrap the codes of tensorflow in one file, and call it in another one:

```
result = 1000
restore = False
path = None
batches = None
while result != 1:
    result, path, batches = main(FLAGS,restore, path, batches)
    if result == -1:
        import gc
        gc.collect()
        time.sleep(300)
        restore = True
```

Now ,the program can pause when the temperature is too high, but the gpu is still occupied and won't cool down. So I wonder how to stop tensorflow and clear the vgram.

The program paused when temperature is too high:
[image]

But the gpu is still occupied and can't cool down:
[image]

Comment: GPUs are not supposed to overheat. I'm guessing you have a fanless Tesla plugged into a system that was not designed for it.

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow only releases all GPU memory after the program exits, that's why you see the memory is not released. Still, I think pause would help, which stops your GPUs are from working at full speed (only 73 out of 149W is being used, as shown in your figure); maybe pause longer if it doesn't cool down immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this problem is solved by adding fans to cool down the GPU ...